# Split text avoiding some cases (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, split

i'm trying to split an html like this as a string:

```
<p class='class1'> Hello, this is my html </p>
```

what i need is to split that html by spaces ignoring the html tags in the split, i am currently getting this result:

```
["<p","class='class1'>","Hello,","this","is","my","html","</p>"]
```

but i need it to treat the tags as a complete word, to get this result:

```
["<p class='class1'>","Hello,","this","is","my","html","</p>"]
```

how can i get to this result?

**EDIT:**

In the javascript side, i'm using a simple split:

```
var text = "<p class='class1'> Hello, this is my html </p>";
var splitText = text.split(' ');
```

In this case splitText would be:

```
["<p","class='class1'>","Hello,","this","is","my","html","</p>"]
```

I tried using Regular expressions like "/[<.*?>,\s]+/" but my result was:

```
var text = "<p class='class1'> Hello, this is my html </p>";
var splitText = text.split(/[<.*?>,\s]+/);

splitText = ["p class='class1'","Hello,","this","is","my","html","/p"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your script here

Comment: Do you need to consider nested HTML tags or only tags with text node children?

Comment: No, i need the result to treat every tag like a word, no matter if it is or not inside another tag. so if i have:

`<p class='class1'><p class='class2'>Hello world</p></p>`

i'd like my result to be:

`["<p class='class1'>","<p class='class2'>","Hello","world","</p>","</p>"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this by using a simple regular expression and the match method.

```
var text = "<p class='class1'><p class='class2'>Hello world!</p></p>";
var splitText = text.match(/[\<].+?[\>]+|[^\s]+/g);

//splitText -> 
//["<p class='class1'>","<p class='class2'>","Hello","world!","</p>","</p>"]
```

Thanks @MaveRick for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $("<p class='class1'>Hello, this is my html</p>");
var b = a.html().split(' ');
a.html('');
var c = a[0].outerHTML.split('><');
b.splice(0, 0,c[0]+'>');
b.splice(b.length+1, 0,'<'+c[1]);
```

b will result: `["<p class="class1">", "Hello,", "this", "is", "my", "html", "</p>"]`

**Note:** This code is only for one dimension tag